# Intitalize Solana Program through IDL

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-client, idl

I want to initialize solana program through IDL using rust (anchor-client) program as same as we do in JS

```
let programNetworkDemand = new Program(
IDL,
programIDNetworkDemand,
provider,
);
```

I didn't able to initailize program in anchor_client

Comment: That's not Rust code. Have you tried doing it in Rust yet? Please post what you have tried and the error you are getting so we can help.

Comment: @sohrab The code snippet I shared above is TS code I need to implement same thing on rust but I am unable to find how can I initilaze program in rust

Comment: as far as am aware this does not exist in the anchor rust client (it does not get the same love the anchor-ts gets xD) , the feature you are in search of only exist on the ts side am not sure on this, hopefully someone with more idea can add to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, anchor_client is not IDL-aware. It is intended for scenarios where you have access to the source code (or crate) of the program you are calling.

You can see an example of this the [Anchor github repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/client/example/src/main.rs):

```
program
    .request()
    .signer(&counter)
    .accounts(basic_2_accounts::Create {
        counter: counter.pubkey(),
        user: authority,
        system_program: system_program::ID,
    })
    .args(basic_2_instruction::Create { authority })
    .send()?;
```

Here, the Account and argument structs from the Tutorial 2 program have been used to compose the transaction.