# how to generate and sign a orca swap tx by rust?

Tags: anchor, rust

How to generate orca whirlpool swap tx and sign it by rust. I found orca ts sdk, but I need some rust demo. I used anchor-gen to generated crate, but how to use it?

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/172/411